# Can you end a sentence with 'so' in this way?

Tags: grammaticality, archaicisms, sentence-ends

For example, "Why do you love him so?"
If you can, under what circumstances are you allowed to use it? I don't see it used often, so if it the usage is allowed, would I be correct in assuming it's an archaic usage of the word?

If not, then never mind.

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not archaic. Look at the definition and examples sentences for *so* in the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/so). In definition 1.1 there is a sentence/clause ending with  *so* as one of two sample uses ('I do love it so’). In  'More Example Sentences' there is another example of *so* ending an independent clause: 'I  wanted to like the movie if only because the critics hated it so,'

You can use it whenever you want to end an independent clause with *so*.

Answer (score 1):

"Why do you love him so?" essentially translates to "Why do you love him so much".

It's somewhat archaic, but fans of such writing keep it alive, at least as an affectation.

Comment: I'd say *dated* rather than *archaic*. BTW, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: We're deep into opinion here. I think of it as maybe being in popular usage before I was born, and i'm in my early fifties. A table that old is considered an antique, so...

Comment: Well, tables aren't vocabularies. *Archaic* in the context of language refers to words used in earlier times and no longer current except to evoke those times. A few minutes spent in the google will tell you that *I love you so* is a common locution in love songs and children's books current during your lifetime.